# Extract texts between quotes in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have some text files like this:

```
proc p0
ans12=2
do while ans12#1
  * set print to "lp -dACCPRN"
   clos data
   @0,0 clea
   @3,36,21,65 box
   @3,4,21,32  box
   @4 ,40 prom '                0šø¤‹‹¡ ' &&1
   @6 ,40 prom '                ù‹ê‘‹® ' &&2
   @7 ,40 prom '  –‘“¨‘Ÿõ ¤÷–‘Ÿþ®ø—¢ø¤ø ' &&3
   @8 ,40 prom '               ù¢û‘‹‹ªõ ' &&4
   @9 ,40 prom '                žò‹‹‹¬ ' &&5
```

Now I need to search trough all text file and extract that texts which is in between quotes

Result would be like:

```
'                0šø¤‹‹¡ '
'                ù‹ê‘‹® '
'  –‘“¨‘Ÿõ ¤÷–‘Ÿþ®ø—¢ø¤ø '
'               ù¢û‘‹‹ªõ '
'                žò‹‹‹¬ '
```

Comment: Use Pos and Copy

Answer (score 3):

You could use a function to filter out the quoted text from each line:

```
function TextBetweenQuotes( const s : String; quoteChar : Char) : String;
var
  p,p1 : Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  p := Pos(quoteChar,s);  // Find first quote char
  if p > 0 then begin
    p1 := Pos(quoteChar,s,p+1); // find second quote char
    if p1 > 0 then begin
      Result := Copy(s,p,p1-p+1);  // Copy text between quotes, including quotes
    end;
  end;
end;
```

If you have an older Delphi version which does not support optional offset argument in the [Pos()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Pos) function, use the [StrUtils.PosEx()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.PosEx) instead.